# Swift: Check has a protocol and use getter Like you would in Java

Tags: ios, swift, generics, reflection, protocols

I was wondering if it is possible to check if a class conforms to a protocol in swift.

I have an EntityObject class, which contains some basic functionality in Java I'd make it abstract but since swift doesn't do abstraction I'm running it like this.

I also have an Entity Protocol which requires a getter for a path property (which does not really exist but always returns the path in our API).

Now in the EntityObject class which is always extended (otherwise you get fatalError's in your face). I want to get this path but EntityObject does not conform to the Entity Protocol but it's children do in most cases.

example path getter:

```
class var path:String {get { return "blog/{blogId}/comments" } }
```

The getters do not show up in the Mirror using reflect() probably because it's a class(static) var, and I tried something like:

```
if let entity = self as? Entity {
    return entity.path
}
```

But this returns an instance of Entity (I guess) since I'm not allowed to use the path here or see any of the options.

Anyone know if I could do this generically?

Comment: You are asking to check if a class conforms to a protocol, but your question is otherwise

Comment: Note entirely true, it already stated I just wanted to access a variable, and therefore I thought I should be able to "cast" it to a protocol. Which was not necessary it seemed.

Thanks for the downvote though. I edited the Title so it actually reflects the content of the question even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the property I wanted to invoke was not an instance, but a Type property I couldn't get it from the instance, the dynamicType property does however let me. So in my case it would be.

```
    if let path = self.dynamicType.valueForKey("path") as? String {
        return path
    }
```

This will fetch the path var as string if it is there. Making my entire function:

```
func getPath() -> String? {
    if let path = self.dynamicType.valueForKey("path") as? String {
        return path
    }

    ErrorClass.log("Path not implemented on \(self), does not inherit from entity?")
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a class conforms to protocol in swift as:

```
 if myClass.conformsToProtocol(ProtocolName) {
    //class conforms to protocol
 }
```

Comment: for some reason it won't let me, it keeps asking me to instantiate the protocol or add comma's I found a working solution for my exact case though I'll post this.

Comment: This will only work for Objective-C classes, like `NSObject` subclasses. `conformsToProtocol` won't work for pure Swift classes.